How to group a list of lists into a new list based on the beginning character of one of the elements in one of the lists
I have a lists of lists called "lines" that looks like this:
[['INS', 'Y', '18', '024', '07', 'A', '', '', 'TE'],
['REF', '0F', '708066255'],
['REF', '1L', '708066255'],
['DTP', '303', 'D8', '20240901'],
['DTP', '356', 'D8', '20240801'],
['NM1', 'IL', '1', 'FIGUEROA', 'LILIET', '', '', '', '34', '536899858'],
['N3', '2670 SO A W GRIMES BO', '#6102'],
['N4', 'ROUND ROCK', 'TX', '786642849', '', 'CY', '246'],
['DMG', 'D8', '19931219', 'F', '', 'H'],
['INS', 'Y', '18', '024', '07', 'A', '', '', 'TE'],
['REF', '0F', '811229070'],
['REF', '1L', '811229070'],
['DTP', '303', 'D8', '20240901'],
['DTP', '356', 'D8', '20240201'],
['NM1', 'IL', '1', 'MORILLO RUZA', 'OMARLY', 'V', '', '', '34', '000000000'],
['PER', 'IP', '', 'HP', '5129233526'],
['N3', '154 TERRI TL'],
['N4', 'ELGIN', 'TX', '786218937', '', 'CY', '011'],
['DMG', 'D8', '20040628', 'F', '', 'H']]

What I need is to group the lists into new lists wherever the 'INS' element appears in one of the lists.  The output should look like:
[[['INS', 'Y', '18', '024', '07', 'A', '', '', 'TE'],
['REF', '0F', '708066255'],
['REF', '1L', '708066255'],
['DTP', '303', 'D8', '20240901'],
['DTP', '356', 'D8', '20240801'],
['NM1', 'IL', '1', 'FIGUEROA', 'LILIET', '', '', '', '34', '536899858'],
['N3', '2670 SO A W GRIMES BO', '#6102'],
['N4', 'ROUND ROCK', 'TX', '786642849', '', 'CY', '246'],
['DMG', 'D8', '19931219', 'F', '', 'H']],
[['INS', 'Y', '18', '024', '07', 'A', '', '', 'TE'],
['REF', '0F', '811229070'],
['REF', '1L', '811229070'],
['DTP', '303', 'D8', '20240901'],
['DTP', '356', 'D8', '20240201'],
['NM1', 'IL', '1', 'MORILLO RUZA', 'OMARLY', 'V', '', '', '34', '000000000'],
['PER', 'IP', '', 'HP', '5129233526'],
['N3', '154 TERRI TL'],
['N4', 'ELGIN', 'TX', '786218937', '', 'CY', '011'],
['DMG', 'D8', '20040628', 'F', '', 'H']]]

Im unsure how to do this

I cannot see any difference between the lists from a quick scan, and you haven't shown any effort yourself here. The question is totally unclear to me

The seocond list has 2 lists grouped by the INS element

it is very unclear. using the word sublist could help. please reformulate both title and content

What if the first row doesn't have 'INS'? What is holding you back to just do what you described?

iterate through intial list, check if first element is INS or not, and based on that structure your final output
below is example
x = [
        ['INS', 'Y', '18', '024', '07', 'A', '', '', 'TE'],
        ['REF', '0F', '708066255'], ['REF', '1L', '708066255'],
        ['DTP', '303', 'D8', '20240901'],
        ['DTP', '356', 'D8', '20240801'],
        ['NM1', 'IL', '1', 'FIGUEROA', 'LILIET', '', '', '', '34', '536899858'],
        ['N3', '2670 SO A W GRIMES BO', '#6102'],
        ['N4', 'ROUND ROCK', 'TX', '786642849', '', 'CY', '246'],
        ['DMG', 'D8', '19931219', 'F', '', 'H'],
        ['INS', 'Y', '18', '024', '07', 'A', '', '', 'TE'],
        ['REF', '0F', '811229070'],
        ['REF', '1L', '811229070'],
        ['DTP', '303', 'D8', '20240901'],
        ['DTP', '356', 'D8', '20240201'],
        ['NM1', 'IL', '1', 'MORILLO RUZA', 'OMARLY', 'V', '', '', '34', '000000000'], 
        ['PER', 'IP', '', 'HP', '5129233526'], 
        ['N3', '154 TERRI TL'], 
        ['N4', 'ELGIN', 'TX', '786218937', '', 'CY', '011'], 
        ['DMG', 'D8', '20040628', 'F', '', 'H']
]

sol = []
tmp = []



for i in x:
    if i[0]!="INS":
        tmp.append(i)
    else:
        if tmp:
            sol.append(tmp)
        tmp = [i]

if tmp:
    sol.append(tmp)

print(sol)

# output
"""
[
    [
        ['INS', 'Y', '18', '024', '07', 'A', '', '', 'TE'],
        ['REF', '0F', '708066255'],
        ['REF', '1L', '708066255'],
        ['DTP', '303', 'D8', '20240901'],
        ['DTP', '356', 'D8', '20240801'],
        ['NM1', 'IL', '1', 'FIGUEROA', 'LILIET', '', '', '', '34', '536899858'],
        ['N3', '2670 SO A W GRIMES BO', '#6102'],
        ['N4', 'ROUND ROCK', 'TX', '786642849', '', 'CY', '246'],
        ['DMG', 'D8', '19931219', 'F', '', 'H']
    ],
    [
        ['INS', 'Y', '18', '024', '07', 'A', '', '', 'TE'],
        ['REF', '0F', '811229070'],
        ['REF', '1L', '811229070'],
        ['DTP', '303', 'D8', '20240901'],
        ['DTP', '356', 'D8', '20240201'],
        ['NM1', 'IL', '1', 'MORILLO RUZA', 'OMARLY', 'V', '', '', '34', '000000000'],
        ['PER', 'IP', '', 'HP', '5129233526'],
        ['N3', '154 TERRI TL'],
        ['N4', 'ELGIN', 'TX', '786218937', '', 'CY', '011'],
        ['DMG', 'D8', '20040628', 'F', '', 'H']
    ]
]
"""


A simple loop should work:
new_list=[]
# data is the original list
for sublist in data:
    if sublist[0] == "INS": new_list.append([])
    new_list[-1].append(sublist)


If the first element doesn't start with INS, this will try to access new_list[-1] when new_list is empty.

As trincot asked above, the question doesn't explain what should happen in this case.

Left as an exercise for the OP.
